# selenium error(while taking a screenshot) 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, selenium, encode

I am using selenium on Google Cloud Platform and geckodriver to take a screenshot of a page but
my selenium throws an error like this...

```
get_screenshot_as_png

return base64.b64decode(self.get_screenshot_as_base64().encode('ascii'))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I am using firefox 68.xx and geckodriver 78(I am not sure tho)

```
cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap['marionette'] = True
#cap['binary'] = '/usr/local/bin/firefox'

options = Options()
#options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")


date_time  = datetime.datetime.now()
page_time = datetime.timedelta(hours = +9)
print(page_time+date_time)
page_time = page_time + date_time
page_time = page_time.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')

driver.save_screenshot(page_time+"screen.png")
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: you should show the full code.

Comment: thank you ive just added it

Comment: yeah @MosheSlavin actually there are some code snippet in between for importing datetime module etc. So you think that might cause trouble too? I will update those accordingly now thanks

Comment: @MosheSlavin My console time is incorrect in my time zone so I just adjusted using it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so this issue is because you are using `.` to separate the date.

Try changing it to `-`:

```
page_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Oh I really appreciate your help!! I didn't even know that would be the cause of my problem!! So I can't use dot even if I use escape character in that string? Thank you for you help again!:))